# Replace characters using regex grouping with sed

Tags: regex, sed, grouping, backreference

I have a text file that is like this:

```
FOO BAR PIPPO PLUTO 31337 1010
FOOZ BAZ 130
VERY LONG LINE LIKE THIS THEN A NUMBER LIKE 42
```

I need to turn it into:

```
FOO-BAR-PIPPO-PLUTO 31337 1010
FOOZ-BAZ 130
VERY-LONG-LINE-LIKE-THIS-THEN-A-NUMBER-LIKE 42
```

The best I could do is:

```
sed -re 's/([A-Z]+)( )([A-Z]+)/\1-\3/g'
```

but the output is

```
FOO-BAR PIPPO-PLUTO 31337 1010
FOOZ-BAZ 130
VERY-LONG LINE-LIKE THIS-THEN A-NUMBER LIKE 42
```

Close, but no cigar. Any idea on why my regex doesn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have overlapping matches. "BAR PIPPO" isn't detected because "BAR" was already consumed when matching "FOO BAR".

```
FOO BAR PIPPO PLUTO 31337 1010
------- ===========
   1         2
```

Try this instead:

```
$ sed -re 's/ ([A-Z])/-\1/g'
```

Note that this doesn't have overlapping matches:

```
FOO BAR PIPPO PLUTO 31337 1010
   --  ==    --
   1   2     3
```

Comment: OK, That's good enough, thanks for the explanation about overlapping!

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ \([^0-9]\)/-\1/g'
```

Just look for *space followed by not a number* and replace that space with a `-`.  The advantage of this is that it will work for lines that have non-alphanumeric characters.

#### Proof of Concept

```
$ cat ./infile
FOO BAR PIPPO PLUTO 31337 1010
FOOZ BAZ 130
VERY LONG LINE LIKE THIS THEN A NUMBER LIKE 42
THIS LINE HAS $ODD$ #CHARS# IN %IT% 42

$ sed 's/ \([^0-9]\)/-\1/g' ./infile
FOO-BAR-PIPPO-PLUTO 31337 1010
FOOZ-BAZ 130
VERY-LONG-LINE-LIKE-THIS-THEN-A-NUMBER-LIKE 42
THIS-LINE-HAS-$ODD$-#CHARS#-IN-%IT% 42
```

Answer (score 0):

Very close.  You don't need to match more than one letter though - you just want letter space letter:

```
sed -Ee 's/([A-Z])( )([A-Z])/\1-\3/g' foo.txt 
FOO-BAR-PIPPO-PLUTO 31337 1010
FOOZ-BAZ 130
VERY-LONG-LINE-LIKE-THIS-THEN-A NUMBER-LIKE 42
```

(sed params adjusted for BSD sed)

Comment: That doesn't quite work for the third example. It misses the space in `THEN-A NUMBER`. But good idea to match only one character, I've updated my answer too.